# Footer overlapping webpage in mobile landscape mode only, also bottom contents/div cutting from bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

Footer is overlapping in my webpage in mobile landscape view only. Also, the bottom contents of a `<div>` are not coming properly. Please guide. I have attached screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of webpage in mobile - Landscape view]

CSS file for footer

```
#footer {   
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I have added my JS code as well for more information.
Pls guide how to prevent the overlapping.
JS Code

```
function getScereenWidthHeight()
{
var isAndroidApp = $('#isAndroidApp').val();
if(isAndroidApp == 'true')
{
    var screenWidth = 0;
    var screenHeight = 0;   
    var dpi = 0;
    var screenWidthInches = 0;
    var screenHeightInches = 0;
    var thresholdScreenSize = 7;


    //Get device DPI

    dpi = document.getElementById("dpi").offsetHeight;

    //get screen height and screen width in pixels

    screenWidth = screen.width;

    screenHeight = screen.height;

    //convert screen height and width in inches, formula: Pixels ÷ DPI = Inches 

    screenWidthInches = Math.round(screenWidth/dpi);

    screenHeightInches = Math.round(screenHeight/dpi);

    if(screenWidthInches > thresholdScreenSize || screenHeightInches > thresholdScreenSize)
    {
        document.getElementById("centeredDiv").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("footer").style.display = "inline"; 
    }    
    else
    {
        if(document.getElementById("androidErrorTxt") != null && document.getElementById("androidErrorTxt") != 'undefined')
        {
            document.getElementById("androidErrorTxt").style.display = "inline";
            document.getElementById("footer").style.display = "inline";
        }               
    }
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("centeredDiv").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("footer").style.display = "inline"; 
}
}


function getFooter(  )
{

 var myDiv9= "<p>" + eTextIpadCopyrightMsg ;
    myDiv9 += "<a href=\"" + eTextIpadLegalUrl + "\" class=\"footermenulink\">" + eTextIpadLegalUrlText + "</a> |   " ;
    myDiv9 += "<a href=\"" + eTextIpadPrivacyUrl + "\" class=\"footermenulink\">" + eTextIpadPrivacyUrlText + "</a> |   " ;
    myDiv9 += "<a href=\"" + eTextIpadPermissionsUrl + "\" class=\"footermenulink\">" + eTextIpadPermissionsUrlText + "</a> |   " ;
    myDiv9 += "<a href=\"" + eTextIpadSupportUrl + "\" class=\"footermenulink\">" + eTextIpadSupportUrlText + "</a>" ;
    myDiv9 += "</p>" ;
    $("#footer").append(myDiv9);

}
```

Comment: can u share your code or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @Raj_King .. Added JS code

Comment: Remove position absolute property and botton property also...the html css should be written such a way that it shouid automatically allocates spaces to div p ... etc

Comment: its working fine for landscape mode but in portrait the footer is pulled up from the bottom

Comment: are you creating mobile app or web app

Comment: I m creating both
but this page is specifically for mobile app

Comment: Try to add one extra div  <div class="clear"></div> before footer div  <div id="footer"></div>

Comment: Put your image and button in one div element and the text in another and apply style. do not use position absolute.. try to use bootstrap for better alignments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
      <div class="clear"></div>

      <div id=footer>
       ....
       ....
      </div> 

     #footer
     {
      width:100%;
      text-align: center;
     }

     .clear
     {
      clear: both;
     }
```

Comment: any luck from the above solution

Comment: not really, when removing position the footer moves up in portrait mode

Comment: r u adding footer before content of the page...I mean the html should be in  the following order <div id="header">..............</div> <div class="clear"</div>  <div id="content">..................</div> <div class="clear"></div><div id="footer">...................</div>

Comment: r u adding html portion via JS code or simply writting html portion in html page... check how it is rendering in browser

Answer (score 0):

Removed position absolute property and bottom property from css page.
Now, I am able to view page without footer overlapping in landscape view.
Thanks.